# How do I prevent bash from escaping backslash in my npm script?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm, sed

my npm script needs to run sed to replace some string, e.g.

```
"prebuild":"sed 's/http:\/\/example.com/https:\/\/something_real.com/' < static/config.js.example > static/config.js",

"build": "node build/build.js"
```

But the backsplash escapes are interpreted by shell when run `npm run build`, so I got the error,

```
qiulang$ npm run build
> sed 's/http://example.com/https://something_real/' < static/config.js.example > static/config.js

sed: 1: "s/http://emicall-cmb.em ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'e'
```

So how do I prevent shell from doing that ?

Comment: I think why `\/` didn't work here may be because it is inside double quotes and therefore you need `\\/` , using different delimiter is better.. also, you would need to escape `.` in search portion of substitute command, as it is a metacharacter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different character as delimiter

```
sed 's@http://example.com@https://something_real.com@' < static/config.js.example > static/config.js
```